# Наиболее простые способы генерации контента Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Каким способом или плагином можно сгенерировать боксы с картинками и описаниями в WordPress? Некоторые платные темы поддерживают такие функции, однако интересен способ реализации наиболее низкоуровневыми способами в рамках разумного.

Пример на картинке:

[image: картинке]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [advanced custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) с аддоном repeater. Добавляете группу полей для статей или страниц, в нем добавляете repeater с картинкой, заголовком, текстом под заголовком и ссылкой (если нужно).

В шаблоне добавляете вывод этих произвольных полей. Оформляете как вам нужно в стилях и все.

И потом в админке пользователь сможет создавать бесконечное кол-во таких штук на разных страницах